# How to round up amount by big-decimals in android

Tags: android

My requirement is when amount is `4.99` divide by `5` should give `0.99` (*its should not be consider as 1*) and `100000.01` divide by `2` should give `50000.01`(*it should not be consider as 50000*).

I tried `BigDecimal.ROUND_UP`, `BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN` both not giving exactly result.

Can any one help how to fix above problem using Big decimals.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

4.99 / 5 = 0.998; the nearest value rounded to 2 decimals is therefore 1.00. Only when you round down it would give 0.99. On the other hand, 100000.01 / 2 = 50000.005; this can only give 50000.01 if you round up.

Therefore, there is no way to get both desired results with one rounding mode.

Comment: is there any way to use both mode together for divide operation some thing like that?

Comment: how to get both result using big decimals?

Comment: without any rounding mode, can we divide amount with scale of 2?